# Pip seems not to be installing module in setup.py

Tags: python, module, pip, anaconda

I have a `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name='yeet',
  install_requires=[
    'cmake>=3.15.3',
    'Cython>=0.29.21',
    'glob2>=0.6',
    'hdbscan>=0.8.24',
  ],
)
```

When I run `python setup.py install` using a Python 3.7 conda environment, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 66, in <module>
    'pixplot=pixplot:parse',
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 117, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run(show_deprecation=False)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 408, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 650, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 697, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 742, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 669, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 880, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1150, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1134, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 257, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 164, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 139, in resume
    raise exc.with_traceback(self._tb)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 254, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/var/folders/cy/ywx04ttn12n_xmgjf5s6sbzr0000gn/T/easy_install-ogn8e84n/hdbscan-0.8.26/setup.py", line 94, in <module>
ImportError: Cython not found! Please install cython and try again
```

Does anyone know why Cython isn't installed, given the fact that it's in my `setup.py` file? I know I can install Cython, but I'd like to prevent users from hitting this snag. Is the solution here for `hdbscan` to add Cython to its list of dependencies? Any pointers others can offer would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this.

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    ...
    setup_requires=[
        'setuptools>= 50.3.0',
        'cython',
```

or something like this.

```
from setuptools import dist
dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs('Cython>=0.29.21')
```

Look in to the following post for more details.
https://luminousmen.com/post/resolve-cython-and-numpy-dependencies

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?